# Do stylistic questions belong here or on programmers.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I was surprised to find a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop) about coding style was migrated to codereview.SE from programmers.SE, since in the past [such](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58630/how-far-should-var-and-null-coalescing-operator-be-entertained-without-ham) [questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/should-if-statments-be-in-inner-or-outer-method) have been migrated in the other direction. Which site should these questions belong on or do they not have a home in the stack exchange network?

Answer (score 7):

I believe [my answer on the specified question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop/1713#1713), and the reply of the poster give a clear indication why this question (and others alike) shouldn't be migrated to Code Review.

Notice his ending question:

> However, some programmers dislike
>   putting that stuff into the FOR,
>   because they think it's being too
>   "clever".
>
> What is your opinion on this and your
>   rationale for thinking so?

His real question **wasn't to review the code** posted, it was only meant to be an example. I treated it as a Code Review, evoking the somewhere understandable response:

> 5. READ THE QUESTION. I'm not talking about this specific implementation of Reverse. I'm talking about use of logic in for loops. Reverse is the algorithm I happened to be using as an example when the question came up, but critiquing how I threw this together in 30 seconds is not the point.

If I would have read the question on Programmers.SE instead, I would have treated it differently and probably would have attempted to answer on the general topic of for loops vs while loops.

Answer (score 5):

Great examples in your post to chew on. A few thoughts.

1. Programmers is less about actual code and more about [whiteboarding ideas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/). So any question with a *lot* of concrete code (versus mostly code concepts with a bit of code to describe those concepts)  is going to be a poor fit there.
2. Stack Overflow is a great place for concrete code but a poor fit for subjective observations *about* code.
3. Code Review is a place for *functioning, error free* code which needs some kind of peer review.

It seems like a reasonable fit to me here, but it could possibly squeak by on any of the above sites, honestly...

I do not think the migration was necessarily wrong, but it certainly seems workable on Programmers. I would be interested to hear what others think.

Comment: Jeff, this answer could (and perhaps) should be posted on meta.programmers to point people in the right direction about flagging this site as a possible destination.

Answer (score 3):

As the moderator on Programmers' who migrated the question I can only apologise if I got it wrong.

The question picked up a number of flags that indicated that it might be better off on this site so I took that decision. Perhaps I should have investigated further before doing so.

If a question does get migrated incorrectly, the best procedure is to follow the link back to the original question and flag that for moderator attention. Explain what's gone wrong and a moderator on the original site can clear the migration history. You can then delete the question from here.

Comment: I don't think it was off topic at Programmers. That's kind of the point!

Comment: @Jeff - I understand that & I'll remove the last sentence as it does confuse the issue.

Comment: That's ok, I'm still trying to work out where to draw the line myself (hence the question).

Answer (score 2):

There is some overlap between codereview.SE and programmers.SE, no doubt, but I feel stylistic questions should go here. Programmers is more about the process of programming, this is about the code, so to speak. At least in my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the question is one of the few that could easily fit on both Code Review *and* Programmers. On the Code Review side, it fits two requirements from the [faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

- **Specific feedback about...Best practices and design pattern usage in your code** - The question is about best practices
- **Make sure you include your code in your question** - The question includes a working example

On the Programmers [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

- **Software Engineering** - The question is about readability, which SE encourages
- **Good subjective questions...inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.** - The question is phrased as such. "What is your opinion on this and your rationale for thinking so?"

In this case I think the migration didn't hurt anything. It has gotten two good answers so far. Questions like [Tabs versus spaces—what is the proper indentation character for everything, in every situation, ever?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/57/6415) are *completely* off-topic here since they do not include code and are entirely subjective. I'm inclined to allow most questions that have working code written to solve a programming problem in them - this would exclude code (if there is any) written to prove that indenting 3 spaces is superior to 4.

Comment: Tabs vs. spaces is also off topic on Programmers ;) It's almost the very definition of "Not Contstructive".